# How to retrieve image files from Sharepoint Image Library (List) through REST API using C# in Windows Store App

Tags: rest, windows-store-apps, sharepoint-2013

I am building a Windows Store App where I have to upload and download images from a SharePoint 2013 site. I tried the REST API but all I am getting is XML data containing the properties of the file but I am not able to get the actual file. Can someone please help me with this?

Following is the code that I am trying with:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/atom+xml");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/atom+xml;type=entry");

var response = await client.GetAsync("server/site/_api/web/ListName/Items(1)/File");
Byte[] bArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Might be helpful [Create a SharePoint Lists reader (Windows Store apps using C# and XAML)](http://havivi.blogspot.in/2012/09/create-sharepoint-lists-reader-windows.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve a specific file content from library:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)/File/$value
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
```

**Example**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

var response = client.GetAsync("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(1)/File/$value", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
var fileContent = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
```

### References

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553%28v=office.15%29.aspx)